# Do svg fonts have ligature tables?

Tags: svg, fonts, fontforge

Do svg fonts use ligature tables? If so, can you point me to an example of what one would look like (it doesn't have to have glyph data)?

I just wanted to make sure before I go changing font data that I exported from out of font forge.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm going to assume you are referring to the type of font with an `.svg` extension.  And not OpenType fonts that contain SVG-based glyphs.*

Information on the capabilities of SVG fonts can be found in the [SVG Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/single-page.html#chapter-fonts).

The answer is no.  SVG fonts are very primitive. They support kerning, and that's about it.

It's also worth pointing out that SVG fonts are deprecated now.  It has been removed from the draft SVG 2 specification.  And support is gradually being [removed from browsers](https://caniuse.com/svg-fonts).

Comment: While this is the correct answer, all I cared about was how ligatures were exported from fontforge to svg fonts - and I know the OP doesn't capture that which is my fault. Which happens to be "some_ligature.liga". I will mark this as the correct answer to my trashy  question (I'm still learning about fonts - I'm new to the game). I understand that they are mostly deprecated, however there are uses for the outside of web browsers. I appreciate the thoughtful answer and you time.

Comment: Ah ok. Good luck with your project.